# React Semantic-UI Horizontal Step

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm looking at the step examples for [React Semantic-UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/step/)

None of the horizontal examples appear to be working in the CodeSandbox provided... they all render vertical. Am I missing something?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zwp4wmmx24?module=/example.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps element is responsive. If you dock the browser piece to the bottom, it will be horizontal. If the width is too small, it stacks vertically automatically.

[image]